# open bokeh server through browser in dataiku

Tags: python, bokeh, data-science-studio

Upon running, bokeh serve --show myapp.py on anaconda prompt in windows(host) opens a web browser. Now, How do I execute the same script on my dataiku platform ( linux virtual box ) so that the web browser opens up

Comment: Though this does seem to be about the programming environment, you may have some luck on the Linux or SuperUser stacks...

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. If you are running a bokeh server on a remote linux machine, there is no way for that remote process to start a browser on your local machine (which is true in general, and has nothing specific to do with the bokeh server). You will have to open a browser locally yourself, and navigate to the remote URL.